# Is there a way to run NSUrlConnection in a background thread using monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, download

I know what you are think, why would he want to run an Asynchronous method in a background thread? The answer is that I am downloading some files locally and the local write process takes a lot of time hanging the UI. This is the case even if I use the async methods of the FileStream class, and creating a new thread every time that ReceivedData is called is to resource intensive, not to mention it opens a lot of problems securing the integrity of the file. All these would of course not be a problem when using the .net classes WebClient or HTTPWebRequest. Only that as mentioned elsewhere [questions/6282278](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282278/webclient-in-monotouch-does-not-finish-file-downloads) these classes doesn't work reliably.

I have tried running the NSUrlConnection from a BackgroundWorker, a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, a NSOperationQueue, and for some reason NSUrlConnection only seems to work when called from the Main Thread. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use the standard .Net classes: HttpWebRequest or WebClient.

I'd avoid any NS-Apple APIs if possible.

Comment: As of Monotouch 5.0 the .net classes WebClient or HTTPWebRequest are working reliably. So I am sticking with those. Thanks.