# WebClient on Monotouch Application stops without finishing download

Tags: xamarin.ios, webclient, xamarin

I am having again ([see old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282278/webclient-in-monotouch-does-not-finish-file-downloads)) problems downloading files using the WebClient class. If I open the App and go directly to a page and start downloading, it works great. But if I first click around for a while and then try to download a file the WebClient downloads the first 1% and then stops, triggering a download complete event without errors. I tried only registering to the DownloadProgressChanged event but the WebClient still stops after 1%. And it is always 1%, not 2% or 3%... The current version of the App "FliteLevelTV" is already on the store and performs the downloads, with exactly the same code, without problem.

I am currently using Xamarin Studio 4.0.8(build2) with Xamarin.iOS Version: 6.2.7.1 (Business Edition).

I first thought that probably my WebClient is being garbage collected before it finishes, but if that was the case it would not trigger the download complete event. In any case, in my App, the whole download system is controlled through a Singleton that has a single instance of the file downloader as class property, which also has a single instance of the WebClient as property, and controls that only one file is downloaded at a time using a queue.So I am not sure how I could architect it differently to be more efficient.

Please help, I really need to push some updates and this issue is holding the whole thing.

Comment: Can you try with an earlier version of Xamarin.iOS to see if that's what changed? Another thing you can try is to create a new project and try to download the files there to see if it's a project-specific problem.

Comment: I have two Projects that use the same code. The problem is the same on both.

Comment: Then please file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case.

Comment: Doing a test case is going to be very difficult. I have done some more tests and the problem only happens after I load a view that shows several video thumbnails. If I trigger the download, even repeatedly from the start screen, without loading this view it works as expected. Any Idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tried monotouch 6.2.2.8 which is as back as I can go on the Xamarin website and same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is tripped by this problem.

I implemented the process with the HttpWebRequest and found the problem. One of the events hooked to the WebClient was making a change to a value object that was triggering a change to the UI, which of course won't work, being the WebClient on a background thread. It looks like in this situation  the WebClient simply swallows the exception, kills the download thread and triggers the completed event without errors.